# JSON - filter array by string

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am working in MS Power Automate (Flow) and I want to filter a JSON array by a string to retrieve the value...

here is a subset of my JSON Data (this data has been extracted from a SharePoint list by a Flow *Get Items* step):

```
[
 {
"@odata.etag": "\"2\"",
"ItemInternalId": "1",
"ID": 1,
"Setting1": {
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
  "Id": 0,
  "Value": "Email Addresses"
},
"Setting1#Id": 0,
"Setting2": {
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
  "Id": 0,
  "Value": "Retail Marketing Team Email"
},
"Setting2#Id": 0,
"Value1": "person1@company.co.uk; person2@company.co.uk; "
},
{
"@odata.etag": "\"2\"",
"ItemInternalId": "2",
"ID": 2,
"Setting1": {
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
  "Id": 0,
  "Value": "Email Addresses"
},
"Setting1#Id": 0,
"Setting2": {
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
  "Id": 1,
  "Value": "Social Media Email"
},
"Setting2#Id": 1,
"Value1": "paidsocial@company.co.uk; person3@company.co.uk; person4@company.co.uk;"     
},
....
]
```

I need to filter that on the field **Setting2** = "search string", and return **Value1** by matching a string

So, for **Setting2** I would use '*Retail Marketing Team Email*' and extract the value of the **Value1** field which is '*person1@company.co.uk; person2@company.co.uk; *'

Now, with `$..['Value1']` I can get all of the **Value1** values, and with filtering I should be able to  retrieve a specific **Value1** element...

I have tried this:

```
$.[?(@.Setting2 == 'Retail Marketing Team Email')]['Value1']
```

and

```
$..['Setting2'].['Value' == 'Retail Marketing Team Email']?['Value']
```

and several other variations but never seem to get any data back, or OI get a JSON Parse error

what is the right way to go about this?

Comment: I don't believe this can be done with jsonpath (since it calls for nested filters). It can probably be done with jsonpath+ or jq.

Comment: @JackFleeting: What about if I did it in two steps - passing the results from the first filter into the second?

Comment: It won't work, I'm afraid. `Value` is a child of `Setting2` while `Value1` is its sibling, so to get to `Value1` you need to get back to `Value`'s parent and then down to the parent's sibling `Value1` - and jsonpath (unlike, for example, xpath) isn't sophisticated enough to do that. In this particular case (but not all), jsonpath+ can help, because it has a "parent" operator.

Comment: @JackFleeting: Thanks, where can I read-up on `Jsonpath+` please? A google search didn't return much useful information...

Comment: You can find more info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus. I'm not aware of a python version, unfortunately.

Comment: @JackFleeting: it occurred to me that I could simplify the source SharePoint list just to two columns: one for **Setting2** and one for **Value1** - then we would just have to filter on one column and return it's sibling *Value1*.
would that work?

Comment: Not really sure. The best way to approach it is to create a new question with the simplified version of the list and post it. Another option, if you can manipulate the SharePoint output, is to save it as xml, which will make the whole process much simpler.

Comment: @JackFleeting: Thanks, I'll create a new question with the simplified list structure ...

Comment: @JackFleeting: I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451441/filter-json-array-using-string-value

Comment: @JackFleeting: and will close this question